# Definition of compactness relative to metric space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I have this theorem below and have questions related to it:

> For any metric spaces $Y \subset X$, a subset $K$ of $Y$ is compact relative to $X \iff$  $K$ is compact relative to $Y.$

First, please, check if the definitions below make sense:

$E$ is open relative to $T \iff \forall p \in E, \exists r> 0, \ N_r(p) \cap T \subset E \subset T,$

$\{F_\alpha\}$ is open cover of $G \iff \forall \alpha, F_\alpha$ is open relative to metric space $U$ where $G \subset U$ and $G \subset \bigcup F_\alpha,$

$S \subset$ (metric space) $Q$ is compact $ \iff \forall \alpha, \exists\{P_1, P_2, \ldots, P_n\} \subset \{P_\alpha\}$ with $S \subset \bigcup P_i$ where $\{P_\alpha\}$ is open cover of $S.$

If the definitions above make sense, how is the definition of compactness of $S$ different from $S$ being compact relative to some metric space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definitions make sense. The difference in the two definitions comes from the definition of open cover. If $S \subseteq Q$, then for the definition of $S$ being compact relative to $Q$, an open cover of $S$ will be a cover by sets that are open with respect to $Q$, whereas if we look at the compactness of $S$ relative to itself, the open cover will consist of open sets relative to $S$.

This distinction is important because a subset $E \subseteq S \subseteq Q$, $E$ could be open relative to $S$ but not to $Q$, and also because an open cover of $S$ (relative to $S$) must of course be by subsets of $S$, whereas an open cover of $S$ (relative to $Q$) can consist of subsets of $Q$ that aren't subsets of $S$.

Comment: So, $K$ compact relative to $Y$ means any open cover of $K$ is open relative to $Y$ and $K$ compact relative to $X$ means any open cover of $K$ is open relative to $X,$ correct? Thanks.

Comment: Absolutely correct :)